# Need a formula for A1 to get the sheet name when the workbook is saved as a template, and still work in other formats when saved

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula in cell A1 that pulls the name of the sheet effectively. I want to distribute this file to multiple people as a template, so they never change the original file. When saved as a macro enabled template, the formula returns as an error, but when saved as a macro enabled file, everything is good. What gives?

This formula works well, but not when the file is saved as a macro enabled template.

`=REPLACE(CELL("filename",A1),1,FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1)),"")`

I need this formula to work on a template and in any other format.

[ERROR when opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK8zv.jpg)

Comment: exactly... what is the "error" message?

Comment: A1 comes out as #Value

Comment: if that's the case.. just proceed to "macro enabled file.." | IMHO, a template is merely an original file where another user/session edits the original one.. Optionally, you may use the [ Review.. > Protect Sheet ] to protect the cell/formula.

Comment: That error comes out in any type of template. I have many macros in that file, so i have to save it as a macro enabled template, so i already know that still doesn't work. There are a lot of co workers who aren't tech savvy, They will move something and mess up the formulas in the cells.... trust me. :). Also, the protect sheet does not work as i have a macro that adds info to a row and another one that deletes rows. When i delete a row, it locks that row and then it cannot be modified, messing up my macro. :/

Comment: Since your target is just "to get the sheet name ".. why not consider a vba solution instead ?

Comment: Can you step through the formula with *Formulas* > *Evaluate Formula* and see what's causing the error?

Comment: Please see the image that i attached to the original question. It says it may have existing arrows or a circular reference.